# The "click" python cli module shows an error main() got an unexpected keyword argument 'get'

Tags: python, python-requests, command-line-interface

So, I am just trying to make a cli that gets the HTML content of a specific page and I have done the following

```py
from colorama import init
import pyfiglet
from termcolor import colored
import click
import requests
import json


@click.command()
@click.option('--get', '-g')
def main(url):
    init() # for colorama
    headline = colored(pyfiglet.figlet_format("C u r l"), "magenta")
    print(headline)
    page = requests.get(url)
    print(page.content)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But when I enter

```
python curl.py  -g "https://google.com"
```

in command prompt, I get this **error**

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "curl.py", line 28, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: main() got an unexpected keyword argument 'get'
```

Comment: Haven't used click myself but the docs suggest that if you create an option called `get`, you should have an argument called `get` in the function you're decorating. Try changing `url` to `get` in your `main` function.

Comment: Thanks Noulaf, the problem is solved now